# Duplicate class error in android studio, flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Following is the error when I try to execute the app, I have tried different methods but nothing working out. Updated flutter, updated the Gradle version to the latest that is 4.1.3 and google service version too that is 4.3.8.

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzu found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzv found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzw found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$ConditionalUserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Event found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$EventInterceptor found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Param found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$UserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zza found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzab found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2
```

---

1. build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}
```

---

2)app/build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appid.com"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```